# Embedded Google map loading only on IE but not loading neither on Mozilla Firefox nor on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have implemented an application with an embedded map which works very well on IE , but does not works well neither on Firefox, nor on Google chrome.

Actually the application should connect to a database, fetch data related to some transmitters and  display markers on the map based on the longitude and latitude values. Everything is fine on IE , but for some reasons the map is not displaying on Firefox and Google chrome. But when I look at the page source for all these browsers, they all look similar, so I don't really understand what is wrong.

I am really stuck, and I would really appreciate if you could help me out !!

Here is a part of the JSP code with the script to retrieve data from the object and display markers:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"> -->
<title>Dashboard (Admin)</title>

<!--  google maps API  -->
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"> </script>

<!-- JQuery Validation Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/configurationUpdate.js"/>"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Bootstrap core javaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/munich.js"/>"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/css/dashboard.css"/>"  rel="stylesheet">
<link   href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript"  src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/munich.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/highstock.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/exporting.js"/>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var lat = [];
var lng = [];
var status = [];
var ipAddress = [];
var height = [];
var currentPower = [];
var prn = [];
var frequencyOffset = [];
var connectivity = [];
var height = [];
var emergencyMessage = [];
var nominalMessage = [];
var iliteId = [];
var transmission = [];
var latitude_tmp = 0;
var longitude_tmp = 0;

<c:forEach items="${iLiteList}" var="ilites" varStatus="status"> 
    status.push("${ilites.status}");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("${ilites.latitude}"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("${ilites.longitude}")); 
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("${ilites.iliteId}");
    prn.push("${ilites.prn}");
    frequencyOffset.push("${ilites.frequencyOffset}");
    currentPower.push("${ilites.currentPower}");
    ipAddress.push("${ilites.ipAddress}");
    height.push(parseFloat("${ilites.height}"));
    connectivity.push("${ilite`enter code here`s.connectivity}");
    emergencyMessage.push("${ilites.emergencyMessage}");
    nominalMessage.push("${ilites.nominalMessage}");
    transmission.push("${ilites.transmission}");
</c:forEach> 

// Map creation 
 var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(48.052562,11.653793); 

 function initialize()
{
     alert(status[0]);

     var mapProp = {
         center:myCenter,
         zoom:18,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

     var map1=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap1"),mapProp); 
        var marker = [] ;
        var latLng = []; 
        /* var infowindow = []; */

        for(i = 0; i<lat.length; i ++){
            latLng [i] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i],lng[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i<lat.length; i ++){

            marker[i]=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:latLng [i],
                map: map1,

                });  

        if((transmission[i]).localeCompare("ON") == 0){
             marker[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'); 
        }else{
             marker[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'); 
        } 

        marker[i].setMap(map1);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', (function(i) {
                return function() {
                     document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat[i];
                     document.getElementById("iLiteID").value = iliteId[i];
                     document.getElementById("status").value = status[i];
                     document.getElementById("ipAddress").value = ipAddress[i];
                     document.getElementById("longitude").value = lng[i];
                     document.getElementById("currentPower").value = currentPower[i];
                     document.getElementById("connectivity").value = connectivity[i];
                     document.getElementById("height").value = height[i];
                     document.getElementById("emergencyMessage").value = emergencyMessage[i];
                     document.getElementById("nominalMessage").value = nominalMessage[i];
                     document.getElementById("prn").value = prn[i];
                     document.getElementById("frequencyOffset").value = frequencyOffset[i];

                     if ((transmission[i]).localeCompare("ON") == 0) {
                             document.getElementById("transmission1").checked = true;

                     } else {
                             document.getElementById("transmission2").checked = true;   
                     }
                     }}(i)));   
                 }               
             }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
........
<div class="row" id="googleMap1" style="width: 100%; height: 50%; margin-left: 3px;" > </div>
........
</body>
</html>
```

The page source codes (script part) for each browser are as follows:

IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lat = [];
var lng = [];
var status = [];
var ipAddress = [];
var height = [];
var currentPower = [];
var prn = [];
var frequencyOffset = [];
var connectivity = [];
var height = [];
var emergencyMessage = [];
var nominalMessage = [];
var iliteId = [];
var transmission = [];
var latitude_tmp = 0;
var longitude_tmp = 0;


    status.push("online");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052562"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653793"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite1");
    prn.push("120");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-100");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.20");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("ON");

    status.push("offline");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052662"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653893"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite2");
    prn.push("128");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-100");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.12");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("OFF");

    status.push("offline");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052862"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653693"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite3");
    prn.push("128");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-154");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.14");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("OFF");

    status.push("online");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052962"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653893"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite4");
    prn.push("128");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-154");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.14");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("ON");


// Map creation 
 var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(48.052562,11.653793); 
 function initialize()
{
     alert(status[0]); 
     var mapProp = {
         center:myCenter,
         zoom:18,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

     var map1=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap1"),mapProp); 
        var marker = [] ;
        var latLng = []; 
        /* var infowindow = []; */

        for(i = 0; i<lat.length; i ++){
            latLng [i] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i],lng[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i<lat.length; i ++){

            marker[i]=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:latLng [i],
                map: map1,

                });  

        if((transmission[i]).localeCompare("ON") == 0){
             marker[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'); 
        }else{
             marker[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'); 
        } 

        marker[i].setMap(map1);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', (function(i) {
                return function() {
                     document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat[i];
                     document.getElementById("iLiteID").value = iliteId[i];
                     document.getElementById("status").value = status[i];
                     document.getElementById("ipAddress").value = ipAddress[i];
                     document.getElementById("longitude").value = lng[i];
                     document.getElementById("currentPower").value = currentPower[i];
                     document.getElementById("connectivity").value = connectivity[i];
                     document.getElementById("height").value = height[i];
                     document.getElementById("emergencyMessage").value = emergencyMessage[i];
                     document.getElementById("nominalMessage").value = nominalMessage[i];
                     document.getElementById("prn").value = prn[i];
                     document.getElementById("frequencyOffset").value = frequencyOffset[i];

                     if ((transmission[i]).localeCompare("ON") == 0) {
                             document.getElementById("transmission1").checked = true;

                     } else {
                             document.getElementById("transmission2").checked = true;

                     }

                     }}(i)));   
                 }                   
            }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Firefox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lat = [];
var lng = [];
var status = [];
var ipAddress = [];
var height = [];
var currentPower = [];
var prn = [];
var frequencyOffset = [];
var connectivity = [];
var height = [];
var emergencyMessage = [];
var nominalMessage = [];
var iliteId = [];
var transmission = [];
var latitude_tmp = 0;
var longitude_tmp = 0;


    status.push("online");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052562"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653793"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite1");
    prn.push("120");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-100");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.20");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("ON");

    status.push("offline");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052662"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653893"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite2");
    prn.push("128");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-100");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.12");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("OFF");

    status.push("offline");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052862"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653693"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite3");
    prn.push("128");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-154");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.14");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("OFF");

    status.push("online");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052962"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653893"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite4");
    prn.push("128");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-154");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.14");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("ON");


// Map creation 
 var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(48.052562,11.653793); 
 function initialize()
{
     alert(status[0]); 
     var mapProp = {
         center:myCenter,
         zoom:18,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

     var map1=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap1"),mapProp); 
        var marker = [] ;
        var latLng = []; 
        /* var infowindow = []; */

        for(i = 0; i<lat.length; i ++){
            latLng [i] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i],lng[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i<lat.length; i ++){

            marker[i]=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:latLng [i],
                map: map1,

                });  

        if((transmission[i]).localeCompare("ON") == 0){
             marker[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'); 
        }else{
             marker[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'); 
        } 

        marker[i].setMap(map1);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', (function(i) {
                return function() {
                     document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat[i];
                     document.getElementById("iLiteID").value = iliteId[i];
                     document.getElementById("status").value = status[i];
                     document.getElementById("ipAddress").value = ipAddress[i];
                     document.getElementById("longitude").value = lng[i];
                     document.getElementById("currentPower").value = currentPower[i];
                     document.getElementById("connectivity").value = connectivity[i];
                     document.getElementById("height").value = height[i];
                     document.getElementById("emergencyMessage").value = emergencyMessage[i];
                     document.getElementById("nominalMessage").value = nominalMessage[i];
                     document.getElementById("prn").value = prn[i];
                     document.getElementById("frequencyOffset").value = frequencyOffset[i];

                     if ((transmission[i]).localeCompare("ON") == 0) {
                             document.getElementById("transmission1").checked = true;

                     } else {
                             document.getElementById("transmission2").checked = true;

                     }

                     }}(i)));   
                 }                   
            }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Google chrome:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lat = [];
var lng = [];
var status = [];
var ipAddress = [];
var height = [];
var currentPower = [];
var prn = [];
var frequencyOffset = [];
var connectivity = [];
var height = [];
var emergencyMessage = [];
var nominalMessage = [];
var iliteId = [];
var transmission = [];
var latitude_tmp = 0;
var longitude_tmp = 0;


    status.push("online");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052562"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653793"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite1");
    prn.push("120");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-100");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.20");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("ON");

    status.push("offline");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052662"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653893"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite2");
    prn.push("128");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-100");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.12");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("OFF");

    status.push("offline");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052862"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653693"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite3");
    prn.push("128");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-154");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.14");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("OFF");

    status.push("online");
    latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052962"));
    longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653893"));      
    lat.push(latitude_tmp);
    lng.push(longitude_tmp); 
    iliteId.push("I_Lite4");
    prn.push("128");
    frequencyOffset.push("0");
    currentPower.push("-154");
    ipAddress.push("192.168.40.14");
    height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
    connectivity.push("connected");
    emergencyMessage.push("random");
    nominalMessage.push("random");
    transmission.push("ON");


alert(status[0]);


// Map creation 
 var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(48.052562,11.653793); 
 function initialize()
{
     alert(status[0]); 
     var mapProp = {
         center:myCenter,
         zoom:18,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

     var map1=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap1"),mapProp); 
        var marker = [] ;
        var latLng = []; 
        /* var infowindow = []; */

        for(i = 0; i<lat.length; i ++){
            latLng [i] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i],lng[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i<lat.length; i ++){

            marker[i]=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:latLng [i],
                map: map1,

                });  

        if((transmission[i]).localeCompare("ON") == 0){
             marker[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'); 
        }else{
             marker[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'); 
        } 

        marker[i].setMap(map1);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', (function(i) {
                return function() {
                     document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat[i];
                     document.getElementById("iLiteID").value = iliteId[i];
                     document.getElementById("status").value = status[i];
                     document.getElementById("ipAddress").value = ipAddress[i];
                     document.getElementById("longitude").value = lng[i];
                     document.getElementById("currentPower").value = currentPower[i];
                     document.getElementById("connectivity").value = connectivity[i];
                     document.getElementById("height").value = height[i];
                     document.getElementById("emergencyMessage").value = emergencyMessage[i];
                     document.getElementById("nominalMessage").value = nominalMessage[i];
                     document.getElementById("prn").value = prn[i];
                     document.getElementById("frequencyOffset").value = frequencyOffset[i];

                     if ((transmission[i]).localeCompare("ON") == 0) {
                             document.getElementById("transmission1").checked = true;

                     } else {
                             document.getElementById("transmission2").checked = true;

                     }

                     }}(i)));   
                 }                   
            }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: Is your `<div>` closed? I know IE is less picky compared to other browsers about tags being closed.

Comment: yes it is closed . I just did not  copy it completely. I have just edited the question and corrected it.  Do you have any clue what could be the problem here ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. What I would suggest though is that you comment out all the code which relates to your transmitters, and see if the map loads in FF/Chrome then. If not strip the HTML right back to the bare bones and try again. Once you get it working on a super simple page, slowly add things back in until it stops working and then you'll know what is causing the problem.

Comment: Also, it's worth double checking in the Firefox & Chrome consoles (press F12) and see if there are any errors being reported.

Comment: I see a javascript error in Chrome with the posted code `Uncaught TypeError: status.push is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a javascript error in Chrome with the posted code `Uncaught TypeError: status.push is not a function`

`status` should not be used as a variable name according to [this list](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)

If I change that to `statusA`, I see a map.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8sjbbs45/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var lat = [];
var lng = [];
var statusA = [];
var ipAddress = [];
var height = [];
var currentPower = [];
var prn = [];
var frequencyOffset = [];
var connectivity = [];
var height = [];
var emergencyMessage = [];
var nominalMessage = [];
var iliteId = [];
var transmission = [];
var latitude_tmp = 0;
var longitude_tmp = 0;


statusA.push("online");
latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052562"));
longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653793"));
lat.push(latitude_tmp);
lng.push(longitude_tmp);
iliteId.push("I_Lite1");
prn.push("120");
frequencyOffset.push("0");
currentPower.push("-100");
ipAddress.push("192.168.40.20");
height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
connectivity.push("connected");
emergencyMessage.push("random");
nominalMessage.push("random");
transmission.push("ON");

statusA.push("offline");
latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052662"));
longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653893"));
lat.push(latitude_tmp);
lng.push(longitude_tmp);
iliteId.push("I_Lite2");
prn.push("128");
frequencyOffset.push("0");
currentPower.push("-100");
ipAddress.push("192.168.40.12");
height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
connectivity.push("connected");
emergencyMessage.push("random");
nominalMessage.push("random");
transmission.push("OFF");

statusA.push("offline");
latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052862"));
longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653693"));
lat.push(latitude_tmp);
lng.push(longitude_tmp);
iliteId.push("I_Lite3");
prn.push("128");
frequencyOffset.push("0");
currentPower.push("-154");
ipAddress.push("192.168.40.14");
height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
connectivity.push("connected");
emergencyMessage.push("random");
nominalMessage.push("random");
transmission.push("OFF");

statusA.push("online");
latitude_tmp = (parseFloat("48.052962"));
longitude_tmp = (parseFloat("11.653893"));
lat.push(latitude_tmp);
lng.push(longitude_tmp);
iliteId.push("I_Lite4");
prn.push("128");
frequencyOffset.push("0");
currentPower.push("-154");
ipAddress.push("192.168.40.14");
height.push(parseFloat("234.0"));
connectivity.push("connected");
emergencyMessage.push("random");
nominalMessage.push("random");
transmission.push("ON");

// Map creation 
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(48.052562, 11.653793);

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap1"), mapProp);
  var marker = [];
  var latLng = [];
  /* var infowindow = []; */

  for (i = 0; i < lat.length; i++) {
    latLng[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i], lng[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < lat.length; i++) {

    marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng[i],
      map: map1,

    });

    if ((transmission[i]).localeCompare("ON") == 0) {
      marker[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
    } else {
      marker[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png');
    }

    marker[i].setMap(map1);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', (function(i) {
      return function() {
        document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat[i];
        document.getElementById("iLiteID").value = iliteId[i];
        document.getElementById("status").value = status[i];
        document.getElementById("ipAddress").value = ipAddress[i];
        document.getElementById("longitude").value = lng[i];
        document.getElementById("currentPower").value = currentPower[i];
        document.getElementById("connectivity").value = connectivity[i];
        document.getElementById("height").value = height[i];
        document.getElementById("emergencyMessage").value = emergencyMessage[i];
        document.getElementById("nominalMessage").value = nominalMessage[i];
        document.getElementById("prn").value = prn[i];
        document.getElementById("frequencyOffset").value = frequencyOffset[i];

        if ((transmission[i]).localeCompare("ON") == 0) {
          document.getElementById("transmission1").checked = true;

        } else {
          document.getElementById("transmission2").checked = true;

        }

      }
    }(i)));
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap1"></div>
```

Comment: I have just tried it and now it works perfectly on Firefox and on Chrome. Thank you so much for your help !! :)